# GoogleStorageException - 401 Unauthorized / Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I want to transfer data from GCS to BigQuery by embulk and digdag.

But error occurs.

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
>
> .......
>
> Error: org.embulk.config.ConfigException: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.

↓ Details

---

command :

```
embulk run XXXX.yaml
```

XXXX.yaml :

```
in:
  type: gcs
  bucket: <bucket name>
  path_prefix: <file path>
  auth_method: compute_engine
  parser:
    type: poi_excel
    sheets: <sheet name>
    skip_header_lines: 4
    columns:
    - {name: 'name', type: string}
        .
        .
        .
out:
  type: bigquery
  mode: replace
  project: <project name>
  dataset: <dataset name>
  table: <table name>
  auth_method: compute_engine
  schema_file: <file name of json type>
  gcs_bucket: <gcs tmp bucket name>
```

output :

```
 $ embulk run target_item_bottoms_config.yaml
2020-07-22 14:27:36.559 +0900: Embulk v0.9.23
2020-07-22 14:27:37.609 +0900 [WARN] (main): DEPRECATION: JRuby org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer is directly injected.
2020-07-22 14:27:40.577 +0900 [INFO] (main): Gem's home and path are set by default: "/Users/oniki/.embulk/lib/gems"
2020-07-22 14:27:41.662 +0900 [INFO] (main): Started Embulk v0.9.23
2020-07-22 14:27:41.853 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-input-gcs (0.3.2)
2020-07-22 14:27:46.263 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-output-bigquery (0.6.4)
2020-07-22 14:27:46.369 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-parser-poi_excel (0.1.7)
org.embulk.exec.PartialExecutionException: org.embulk.config.ConfigException: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$LoaderState.buildPartialExecuteException(BulkLoader.java:340)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(BulkLoader.java:566)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.access$000(BulkLoader.java:35)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:353)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:350)
    at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:22)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.run(BulkLoader.java:350)
    at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:242)
    at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.runInternal(EmbulkRunner.java:291)
    at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.run(EmbulkRunner.java:155)
    at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.runSubcommand(EmbulkRun.java:431)
    at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.run(EmbulkRun.java:90)
    at org.embulk.cli.Main.main(Main.java:64)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doCleanup(BulkLoader.java:463)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$3.run(BulkLoader.java:397)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$3.run(BulkLoader.java:394)
        at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:22)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.cleanup(BulkLoader.java:394)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:245)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.embulk.config.ConfigException: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
    at org.embulk.input.gcs.AuthUtils.newClient(AuthUtils.java:81)
    at org.embulk.input.gcs.GcsFileInput.listFiles(GcsFileInput.java:49)
    at org.embulk.input.gcs.GcsFileInputPlugin.transaction(GcsFileInputPlugin.java:59)
    at org.embulk.spi.FileInputRunner.transaction(FileInputRunner.java:62)
    at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(BulkLoader.java:507)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:226)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.list(HttpStorageRpc.java:366)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$8.call(StorageImpl.java:338)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$8.call(StorageImpl.java:335)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.listBlobs(StorageImpl.java:334)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.list(StorageImpl.java:290)
    at org.embulk.input.gcs.AuthUtils.newClient(AuthUtils.java:77)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:401)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1097)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:499)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.list(HttpStorageRpc.java:356)
    ... 23 more

Error: org.embulk.config.ConfigException: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

my environment :

```
$ gcloud config list
[compute]
region = us-east1
zone = us-east1-c
[core]
account = myname@xxx.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = <project ID>

Your active configuration is: [default]


$ gcloud auth list  
    Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       myname@xxxx.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`



$ gsutil ls   
gs://<bucket name>
```

my gcp IAM role :

owner

---

I understand that the solution to this error is authorization.
But my preferences seem to be fine.

what's wrong?

Comment: Do you run this locally or on compute engine?

Comment: I I was going to run it on compute engine.

Comment: What's the service account of your VM and Is the service account authorized on the bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try locally , and create Service Account Key and save at local .

◾️XXXX.yaml

before

```
auth_method: compute_engine
```

after

```
auth_method: json_key
json_keyfile: /path/to/json_keyfile.json
```

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation [1], if we have 401- Unauthorized error then there could be many reasons, please have a related list of reasons listed below [followed the link 1], which could be helpful for troubleshooting:

Reason:AuthenticationRequiredRequesterPays

Access to a Requester Pays bucket requires authentication.

Reason: authError

This error indicates a problem with the authorization provided in the request to Cloud Storage. The following are some situations where that will occur:
The OAuth access token has expired and needs to be refreshed. This can be avoided by refreshing the access token early, but code can also catch this error, refresh the token and retry automatically.
Multiple non-matching authorizations were provided; choose one mode only.
The OAuth access token's bound project does not match the project associated with the provided developer key.
The Authorization header was of an unrecognized format or uses an unsupported credential type.

reason:lockedDomainExpired

When downloading content from a cookie-authenticated site, e.g., using the Storage Browser, the response will redirect to a temporary domain. This error will occur if access to said domain occurs after the domain expires. Issue the original request again, and receive a new redirect.

Reason: push.webhookUrlUnauthorized

Requests to storage.objects.watchAll will fail unless you verify you own the domain.

Reason: required

Access to a non-public method that requires authorization was made, but none was provided in the Authorization header or through other means.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#401_Unauthorized